# How do I have multiple schemas per database connection in Eclipse DTP?

Tags: database, eclipse, database-connection

I'm using the [Eclipse DTP](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/) to do my SQL development. When I create a database connection I'm promoted to enter the name of the database (schema), and I cannot continue until I enter it. However, I have several databases on each server, and I want to see them all under the database connection (like most the database tools let you).

Can I do it in eclipse?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this other than to create multiple connections?  I know exactly what you are describing and I would like to do the same thing.  The only explanation I can think of is a limitation w/ the MySQL driver.

Comment: @JediPotPie - the mysql driver has no limitation, but as I've stopped using the DTP, I've also didn't find an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each database your should create new Database Connection at Data Source Explorer.
Database connection represent one-to-one mapping database «atomic user instance» (for example, for oracle this is instance name/user name, for hsqldb in server mode databse location and so on) to connection.

Comment: The database connection is to my development machine, where I have root access. I need to access 4-5 schemas. Do you mean I need to create 4-5 database connections? Also, in the SQL editor I can relate the sql to a database connection, and there is another drop down which let me select the schema. Problem is there is only one schema...

Comment: Which db do you use?
I down`t find way, how to add multiply shemas with Oracle or HSQLDB.